# How to modify the model data after it loaded?

Tags: magento2, serialize

I have the **model** that needed to **modify serialized data** to **array** after the form loaded. What is the best way I can use for it? 
I tried to use `_afterLoad()` method, but it worked only for collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Collections load every time when I'm trying to get an item from DB. So the _afterLoad method in collection best way to modify model data.